# Google compute engine load balancing not routing properly

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I am new to Google compute engine and I am try to setup network load balancing having 2 VMs for serving web pages.

For ex, I have 2 VMs - app1 and app2 - both having apache server and serves simple web page.

Both VMs are running with Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)

I am able to access both web pages through the IP in browser.

I created network load balancing setup and both apps are showing in green in target pool which means load balancer is able to connect to both VMs.

But, when I hit the IP of load balancer, it is rendering page from only one server. If I manually stop the server in the VM, load balancer IP redirects to other app. I believe load balancer is able to identify health of both VMs and able to redirect.

But it is not balancing the traffic. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you confirmed session affinity while creating the target pool?

Comment: I didn't want to start with session affinity for the initial setup, so didn't enable that. As per documentation, if I have enabled session affinity with client IP, then this is correct. but without session affinity, it should be going to both VMs in round robin.

Comment: I think network load balancer doesn't forward the traffic on round robin bases. I was able to test it with the load balancer setup that I have. As per the document "By default, to distribute traffic to instances, Google Compute Engine picks an instance based on a hash of the source IP and port and the destination IP and port."
[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/

Comment: Oh. that might be a reason. But as per the video they have provided, it was supposed to do round robin balancing. I applied session affinity now and it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: I will post my comment as an answer so that you can accept it which might help someone else with the similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the network load balancer doesn't forward the traffic on a round-robin basis. I was able to test it with the load balancer setup that I have. As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network):

> By default, to distribute traffic to instances, Google Compute Engine picks an instance based on a hash of the source IP and port and the destination IP and port.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/S load balancing will proxy requests in a round-robin fashion.  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/